# Force USB Location Id

Tags: macos, usb

I'd like to passthrough a USB device (Digispark) to a qemu VM. Unfortunately the device randomly disconnects crashing the machine. Also to programme the device, it is time critical to hit the Arduino upload button very quickly after the device has been connected to a USB port

Macos always assigns a new location ID whenever the device is re-connected, which makes mounting difficult.

Therefore: Is there a way to tell Macos (13.4.1) to use the same Location Id shown in system_profiler, whenever the USB device is plugged in. The identification should happen through Vendor Id and Product Id.

Obviously, that would end in disaster when connecting two similar devices, but that'd be a second-level problem...

Comment: The location ID isn't user configurable.  This is the location on the USB bus where the device is physically found. Think of it like a PCI slot where you can identify which slot address a device is connected to.  If you want to make sure you're always referening the same device, look for the hardware UUID.

Comment: @Allan well, the location ID consists of a bus and an address. The bus is constant (probably the physical location), but the address keeps changing after re-connections. Therefore, the address is not physical. I'm thinking of fixing a UUID (vendor/device combination) mapping to that address. Like an /etc/fstab, but for USB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually. Use the option

```
-device usb-host,vendorid=0x....,productid=0x....
```

There is also a dedicated library for things like that, which can be found [here](https://www.spice-space.org/usbredir.html), but I wasn't able to make that thing work on my setup.

Comment: You could provide a bit more detail about what the package you've linked does so that readers can make an informed decision without having to follow a blind link.

Comment: The link access the web page of SPICE, which states "The SPICE project aims to provide a complete open source solution for remote access to virtual machines in a seamless way so you can play videos, record audio, share usb devices and share folders without complications."

Comment: Please add it to the answer, not as a comment. Comments can be deleted.